# Xamarin Telerik ListView with Button in the cell - button's clicked event won't fire

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, telerik

I'm building a Xamarin Forms page with a Telerik RadListView component. The listview's ItemTapped event works OK, but when I add a button into the ListViewTemplateCell.View, the Button's Clicked event doesn't fire.

XAML:

```
<telerikDataControls:RadListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single"  ItemTapped="List_Tapped">
                <telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell>
                            <telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>

                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label Margin="10" Text="{Binding itemName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />

                                    <Button Text="Button" BackgroundColor="Blue" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,30,0" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
                        </telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
            </telerikDataControls:RadListView>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void List_Tapped(object sender, 
Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls.ListView.ItemTapEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("List item tapped");
}   

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Button clicked");
    DisplayAlert("Alert", "Button was clicked", "OK");
}
```

I'm assuming the ListView's ItemTapped event is overriding the Button's Clicked event... Can anyone help with how I can make the button clickable in this situation?

Comment: pass CommandParameter value

Answer (score 0):

I have a page that's set up a little different from yours and I get buttons on list items to work w/o problem. It may be just that the control has been updated and fixed since you posted, or it may be the difference in how I setup the list. (I think there have been at least 3 updates to the telerik xamarin controls since you posted)

One quick thing to try...make `SelectionMode="None"` and take the tapped handler off...see if your buttons work then. If that works, you can make a tap-able area under the whole list item's grid (transparent, no-text button or something similar)...and then put buttons in the grid (which will be at a higher z-order).

In my case, I don't have an item tapped handler. Instead, I bind the `SelectedItem` two-way to a view model property...this way when the selected item changes, I'm notified:

```
        <telerikDataControls:RadListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItems}"
                                         SelectionMode="Single"
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
```

In my base ViewModel, my base property setter goes like this:

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>( ref T existing, T value, Action whenChanged = null, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "" )
{
  if ( EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals( existing, value ) ) return false;
  existing = value;
  whenChanged?.Invoke( );
  OnPropertyChanged( propertyName );
  return true;
}
```

Note that the setter allows the injection of a method to call when the property actually changes.

...and so a "typical" view model property goes like this (this is the item source):

```
ObservableCollection<T> selectedItems;
public ObservableCollection<T> SelectedItems
{
  get { return selectedItems; }
  set { SetProperty( ref selectedItems, value ); }
}
```

...but, if I have code to do when the property changes, I can do this (this is the property that's bound two-way to the SelectedItem):

```
T selectedItem;
public T SelectedItem
{
  get { return selectedItem; }
  set { SetProperty( ref selectedItem, value, MaybeSelectItem ); }
}
void MaybeSelectItem( )
{
  if ( SelectItem.CanExecute( null ) )
  {
    SelectItem.Execute( null );
  }
}
```

This way, setting values in my view model properties are event-like...and I can, in this case, avoid having an event handler for list item taps...while still getting normal selection behavior...and buttons on the items as well.